# how to disable Just in time debugger from visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2005, debugging

Uninstalled Visual studio and all its components from the add/remove programs. But now each time something crashes, it pops up the just-in-time-debugger which seems to be a remainder from visual studio...

How to remove it once VS is uninstalled ?

Found out that one can disable the popups by deleting the following keys

```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\Debugger

  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\DbgManagedDebugger
```

But that doesnt remove it from the system ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:**
Apparently whether or not the deletion of the regkeys above totally "removes" VS just in time debugger, I found that re-enabling windows default, dr watson fixes the issues where my programs crashed because of VS leaving the debugger after uninstallation.

This can be done by following [these instructions from microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188296).

Scroll down to the "**To enable Dr. Watson**"